# Is the inverse of a projection from fibre bundle to base space asurjective mapping?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

given a bundle $E$ and a base space $X$ is we have a projection $\Pi: E \rightarrow X$. then is $\Pi^{-1}$ a surjective mapping?

I ask this because in the case of mobius strip the base space is $S^1$ and the fibre is a line so  $F=\Pi^{-1}(x)$ where $F$ is the fiber should give the fiber. but it can't so it should give a point on the fiber. and $\Pi^{-1}$ can not be on to.

Comment: $\Pi^{-1}$ is not actually a mapping. Given a subset $A\subseteq X$, then $\Pi^{-1}(A)=\{e\in E\mid \Pi(e)\in A\}\subseteq E$ is just the set of preimages of points in $A$.

Comment: To add to what Tyrone said, you can pick out multiple maps from $X \to E$ that are right inverses to $\Pi$. We call these maps _sections_ of the fibre bundle.